# Relation does not exist GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

Everything worked, but when I cleared the database and started the application again, I get this error: `ERROR: relation "orders" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)`

My code:

```
type Cart struct {
    gorm.Model
    Products JSONB `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"products"`
    OrderID  uint
}
type Jurik struct {
    gorm.Model
    Inn             string `json:"inn" gorm:column:"inn"`
    ...
    OrderID         uint
}
type Phyz struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name    string `json:"name" gorm:column:"name"`
    ...
    OrderID uint
}
type Order struct {
    gorm.Model
    Cart    Cart   `json:"cart"`
    User_id string `json:"user_id"`
    Jurik Jurik `json:"jurik"`
    Phyz  Phyz  `json:"phyz"`
}
```

I really don't understand what could be wrong, because my `Cart` `Jurik` `Phyz` tables are related to `Order`

Comment: It means that you don't have relation 'orders'. Check your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how it works, but my code before looked like this:

```
func Connect() {

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open("postgres://postgres:qwerty@localhost:5432/shop"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Categories{}, &models.Products{}, &models.Pagination{}, &models.Feedback{}, &models.Cart{}, &models.Jurik{}, &models.Phyz{}, &models.Order{})
    DB = db
}
```

Then I tried to make a separate migration for `Order`:

```
func Connect() {

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open("postgres://postgres:qwerty@localhost:5432/shop"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Categories{}, &models.Products{}, &models.Pagination{}, &models.Feedback{}, &models.Cart{}, &models.Jurik{}, &models.Phyz{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Order{})
    DB = db
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I read this somewhere else (forgot where it was) the thing is that when you have a dependent table it's better to do a seperate line for it because if any of these models have foreign key relationships, it's possible that some constraints are not being correctly set up because the dependent tables may not exist yet. The second snippets work because it allows the dependent table created before the "Order" table created...

It's a bit weird, but yeah, in the end it still works...